# Where to find documentation for Azure Search for Cosmos DB via MongoDb API?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-cosmosdb

This page states that you would need to use REST (REST API version 2019-05-06-Preview) to accomplish adding data from Cosmos DB when using the Mongo DB API. Where can I find an updated walk through of this? Or has anyone successfully done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Around halfway down that page there's a section called [Use REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-cosmosdb#use-rest-apis). This section is an up-to-date walkthrough on how to use the REST API to index data in Cosmos DB. Since you're using the MongoDB API for Cosmos DB, make sure when creating the data source to add *ApiKind=MongoDb* to the connection string.